# Mono & Commercial Projects

Tags: mono, commercial

I have read the [licensing FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/Licensing) and from what I understood people are allowed to use Mono in commercial applications. However, I wonder if Microsoft can interfer with this in any way since they own the .NET Framework and, I suppose, every related patent. Can't that a tiny little bit dangerous?

Also, as a side question... Have you ever used it in commercial applications?

Comment: The company I work at is using Mono to provide its software to Linux users.

Comment: You are asking a bunch of programmers if Microsoft could conceivably bring a patent infringement lawsuit against someone? Yes, they can sue anyone they want. I doubt they will but what factual knowledge would you expect us to apply to this question?

Comment: "What factual knowledge would you expect us to apply to this question?": The factual knowledge is whether there actually are any patents on .NET and if deploying a .NET commercial application using Mono is a patent infringement or not.

Answer (score 6):

> The way in which .NET's cross-platform nature is achieved is different from the approach taken by Sun Microsystems with the handling of the Java programming platform. Unlike Java, Microsoft itself does not provide installers of .NET for Mac, Linux, etc. Rather, Microsoft has released a set of formalized specifications that other entities can use as a road map for building .NET distributions of their platform(s) of choice. Collectively, these specifications are termed the CLI.
>   --Andrew Troelsen "Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform"

The CLI is in many ways, more distributable than JAVA. Microsoft has no claim to it, unlike Oracle and Sun Micro-systems over JAVA. They merely defined a specification, such as an RFC, and the mono developers met it. You may need to contend with GPL and make sure you aren't breaking any of their rules though.

And yes, I used it in a Gstreamer based mac application for recording and uploading lectures.

Comment: They could however claim patents on techniques used in it. A number of companies have claimed patents on the basic idea of a VM.

Comment: @Martin I am no lawyer, but it seems to me that the moment you standardize something, you place it out for public consumption. Does Straustoup or AT&T own the patent on c++? I don't know, but the moment that Richard Stallman wrote g++ there wasn't a damn thing they could do about it. You don't put out an RFC on something you have patented.

Comment: There aren't any patents on c++, software patents weren't allowed at the time.  But there are patents on MP3, H264 , DVD and famously GIF (until it expired) - which even if you do a clean room implementation you will violate.

Comment: Ah, you are right about h.264 and the like. I still think this is different though, as the CLI is more like an interface w.r.t other developers. Microsoft doesn't share their code base, they merely say it needs to do this and this. There are many instances where the same class will perform differently based on these different implementations. The closest parallel I can think of would be posix.

Comment: Given that MSFT are currently demanding $15 for every Android phone because they claim it violates some patents I would be nervous of basing a major project on an anti-windows version of an MSFT technology

Comment: "A number of companies have claimed patents on the basic idea of a VM.": Did they? Isn't the idea of using a VM pretty old and widely used? If one can claim a patent on the idea of a VM, then one can also claim a patent on such things as "using a compiler" or "using a client-server architecture", and so on.

Comment: My employer is on the record of rewriting couple of hundred thousand lines C# application to Java just not  to be dependent on whims of MSFT. http://lpeer.blogspot.cz/2010/04/switching-from-c-to-java.html

Comment: @mcepl so he would rather be dependent on the whims of Oracle than MSFT that makes absolutely no sense! MSFT is 10x faster at getting an update and new language features out than anything on JAVA has been since Oracle bought it. If I was going to be platform independent I would just bite the bullet and write the whole damn thing in native code and follow the posix standard and use an open source UI toolkit.

Comment: @JonathanHenson Oracle? What you are talking about? Of course, they use free OpenJDK, certified 100% Java (and 100% free as in "free software").  You don't believe the FUD generated by MSFT that the Java situation is same as C#, do you?

Note that my employer, RHT, produces also JBoss … we do take Java very very seriously, and yes, of course, OpenJDK is part of RHEL, so it is 100% supported by Red Hat without regards what Oracle does or doesn’t do.  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openjdk

Comment: @mcepl and other than the fact that openjdk has a 70 day lead time over Oracle on security fixes and it performs as well or better (it actually holds the record in benchmarks on redhat), how is the situation different from .NET and MONO? In both cases you have a corporation that owns it and the open source community implements an alternative to spec. If Mono was able to keep up with MSFT and actually present better performance (which I haven't seem them do yet) I would think the situation would be very similar.

Comment: Two pieces of difference: a) no patent threats (which is probably the most important reason why RHT won't touch Mono with ten-feet pole), b) this is NOT an "alternative to spec" of the Oracle's Java, but (especially with OpenJDK7 and 8, a little bit less with OpenJDK 6) it IS the same code Oracle provides you, and Oracle itself claims so (even OpenJDK 6 was certified 100% Java). Did I ever heard official endorsement of Mono by MSFT, like certification-level endorsement?

Answer (score 3):

You can use .Net in commercial products without Microsoft's go ahead. It's like Java, it merely runs the bytecode, in this case Common Language Runtime, so you can use it commercially, just like Java. Mono is simply the CLR bytecode environment ported to UNIX-likes.

Comment: It also runs on Windows.